# Multi Color text into Textarea for javafx

Tags: java, css, colors, javafx

I want to show text with different colors in textarea for example I have Text like this "Hello How are you.My name is loc zak " now when this text shown in the textarea hello word has blue color and name has also Blue color remaining  black.I'm checking word with a list of words the matching words has blue color in the textarea can anyone explain with coding by using JavaFX 2.2 with JDK 7